# mysqli_query retorna coluna em branco

Tags: php

Tenho uma query que tem como função retornar colunas de 2 tabelas.

```
SELECT * FROM `Estoque` AS E JOIN `Produtos` AS P ON E.id_produto = P.id_produto
```

Quando essa query é executada dentro do phpmyadmin o resultado é satisfatório, segue a imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pois bem, passando para o php eu tenho a seguinte função:

```
function montarEstoque($conexao)
{
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Estoque` AS E JOIN `Produtos` AS P ON E.id_produto = P.id_produto";
    
   $r = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
   
   $produtos = [];
   
   while($e = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
   {
       $produtos[] = $e;
   }
   
   return $produtos;
    
}
```

A função como esperado funciona, reconhece as tabelas e colunas a serem capturadas, o array é montado e absolutamente nenhum erro é mencionado *(pelo menos não de forma óbvia)*

O meu problema é que a coluna `aparencia` *(presente na imagem)* vem com resultados todos em branco, e nenhum dado é reconhecido do banco de dados, apesar da query ser funcional dentro do phpmyadmin como já dito

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue aqui 4 posições do array de retorno da query mostrando que o index `aparencia` está vazio. *(o padrão segue para todas as 26 posições)* e apenas essa coluna apresenta este comportamento.

```
[0] => Array ( [id_estoque] => 3 [id_produto] => 7 [loja] => [quantidade] => 20 [preco_dinheiro] => 320,00 [preco_cartao] => 340,00 [preco_custo] => [aparencia] => [abertura] => Direita Invertida [fornecedor] => Mugitec [categoria] => Porta [subcategoria] => Palheta [nome] => Porta Palheta 210x60 [medida] => 210x60 [observacoes] => ) 

[1] => Array ( [id_estoque] => 2 [id_produto] => 6 [loja] => [quantidade] => 5 [preco_dinheiro] => 200,00 [preco_cartao] => 220,00 [preco_custo] => [aparencia] => [abertura] => Selecione [fornecedor] => Esquadrivax [categoria] => Janela [subcategoria] => 4 Folhas [nome] => Janela 4 Folhas 100x150 [medida] => 100x150 [observacoes] => ) 

[2] => Array ( [id_estoque] => 4 [id_produto] => 8 [loja] => [quantidade] => 2 [preco_dinheiro] => 80,00 [preco_cartao] => 80,00 [preco_custo] => [aparencia] => [abertura] => [fornecedor] => Esquadrivax [categoria] => Lustre [subcategoria] => [nome] => Lustre 80 cm [medida] => 80 [observacoes] => ) 

[3] => Array ( [id_estoque] => 5 [id_produto] => 10 [loja] => [quantidade] => 20 [preco_dinheiro] => 180,00 [preco_cartao] => 200,00 [preco_custo] => [aparencia] => [abertura] => [fornecedor] => Mugitec [categoria] => Janela [subcategoria] => 2 Folhas [nome] => Janela 2 Folhas 100x150 [medida] => 100x150 [observacoes] => )
```

Eu acredito que o problema deve ser algum erro que me passou despercebido no php, uma vez que a query tem 100% do seu funcionamento dentro do phpmyadmin!

Agradeço a atenção

Comment: Situação diferente, essa coluna tem algum tipo especial? Já tentou fazer a query retornando apenas ela pra ver o resultado?

Comment: O tipo dela é varchar, semelhante as outras colunas. Quando eu faço uma query apenas dela o resultado é 100% satisfatório kkk, vem tudo certinho. E o engraçado e que quando tento adicionar os valores dessa query de coluna única no array da  query mencionada na pergunta, o valor ainda sim continua vazio acredita?  Posso acabar usando dois arrays pra preencher o html, seria uma gambiarra que resolve, mas queria muito entender o que está acontecendo nessa situação.